# Error while building android platform at cmd

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Error at cmd when building ionic project with android

```
[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
    Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
    ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
     at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
     at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (childprocess.js:1087:5)
```

so what is the problem what must I do to fix it ?? I have android sdk on my pc, and m working on windows 10, I have installed nodejs. Can anybody help me

Comment: what OS are you using? your sdk path are not set in  environment variable.

Comment: iam using windows 10, I set it but the same error occurred.unless iam setting it in a wrong way

Comment: ofcourse you are setting it wrong way, only in that case you get this error.

Comment: so how should I set the path? and should I set ANDROID_HOME and android ?

Comment: double check path of sdk you set is right?

Comment: I add the paths but nothing change so I remove it, so if u please can u tell me how to add them to the path

Comment: Go to Advanced System Settings, then go to Environment Variables and select PATH variable to edit. There you have to append there path to platform tools and tools of sdk, for example like this
`;C:\Development\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk\tools`

Comment: I did that now, and the same error appears??! is there anything I must add at system variables??

Comment: just write `android` in command line and hit enter? does it open anything? Plus restart your computer and then check, because sometimes cmd does not recognize changed environment until you restart.

Comment: when I wrote android + enter it says its not recognized.. i'll restart my pc and then I'll see

Comment: I am supposed to post the answer, and you are supposed to accept that :)

Comment: ohh sryy ! am new to it ill delete it and post it thnk u again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Advanced System Settings, then go to Environment Variables and select PATH variable to edit. There you have to append path to platform tools and tools of sdk, for example like this 
 `;C:\Development\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk\tools`

Now go to cmd and run `android`, if that does not open android sdk manager, then it means path has not been set correctly or cmd is not recognizing enviroment variable updtes, in that case restart your computer and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Advanced System Settings, then go to Environment Variables 
Then add new Variables with name  "ANDROID_HOME" and the value will be you SDK path like

> C:\Android\sdk

Make sure to restart visual studio before run again

it will fix